# Hidden content with assistive technology

Tags: accessibility, user-experience, wai-aria, wcag, wcag2.0

I'm a little bit confused of how the hidden content is working with assistive technologies. I'll give you a few examples and would like you to explain me this, please:

1. If I want to make a small popup, that is previously was `display:none;`, how would the user with the AT will understand it's something new, except the fact I will provide a focus to this popup automatically?
2. How should I make accessible image slider? I heard of the `role` and `aria-*` attributes and that only the visible image at the time should be `display:block;` or just visible and all the other images should be `display:none;`. If it is, wouldn't it be confusing for the user with he AT(part of a first question)?
3. Is there something more than the desktop computers requires for the mobile devices. For example, if I want to make a hamburger menu for mobile screens, should links of it be hidden with the `display:none;`? How should I notice the user about the links are now visible?

Answer (score 1):

1. Providing focus is key for a pop-up, and typically to the control that will close it. If, however, your pop-up is not really a pop-up, but just a box of updates perhaps at the top of the page, then you can skip focus and use a live region. In short, it depends what you are doing. Remember that a pop-up is intended to prevent the user from interacting with the rest of the page until a designated action is taken, whereas an updating content block does not carry that restriction.
2. If you are moving focus, not a big deal. The hidden images won't be in the page content so they will not slow the user. In this case, do not use a live region as that will keep interrupting the user as it cycles.
3. In this case by moving focus to a previously hidden nav menu. With good accessible names it will work just fine.

I suspect you are not familiar with [ARIA live regions](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#LiveRegions), though you are aware of focus management.

Live regions can address some of your needs. There are some [live region properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#liveprops) you need to know. If you want a region to be announced as soon as it changes, no matter what the user is doing, then it will be `assertive`. If you want it to wait until the user finishes an interaction, then it will be `polite`. There are [corresponding live region roles](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#chobet) as well, which I show below.

Further, the [`aria-atomic`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-atomic) property will tell the screen reader whether it should announce the entire thing (which is good for an alert message) or just the parts that changed (which might be a better fit for a timer).

Avoid having more than one ARIA live region on a page.

Here is an [example of an offline alert](http://heydonworks.com/practical_aria_examples/#offline-alert). Here is a handy [slideshare that goes into more detail](http://www.slideshare.net/maxdesign/arialive-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly). There is a lot more out there now that you know what to search.